# Will Applications with ARC enabled and with armv6 work below iOS4 versions?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4, automatic-ref-counting

Will Applications with the combination of ARC enabled and armv6 work below iOS4 versions?

Comment: No, it will not. You might get it working if you are not using any _weak ownership.

Comment: @rokjarc thanks for ur quick responce, can u pls elaborate.

Comment: I edited my comment. It could work - but i really really wouldn't go there unless absolutely neccessery.

Comment: If i'm not mistaking _weak references are supported for iOS >= 5.0. What's your deployment target OS set to in XCode?

Comment: There is a problem with the releaase mechanize that ARC uses that is not available on iOS 4.1 and lower. And you can use `weak` but you can use `unsafe_unretain`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> ARC is supported in Xcode 4.2 for Mac OS X v10.6 and v10.7 (64-bit
>   applications) and for iOS 4 and iOS 5. Weak references are not
>   supported in Mac OS X v10.6 and iOS 4.

Since weak reference is not supported in pre iOS 5.0 versions, I don't think you can run ARC enabled projects in older projects.

EDIT : Thanks @rokjarc for mentioning about `unsafe_unretained`, which will work on iOS 4 above devices to replace weak reference. But the answer to OP's question about "Will ARC project work on pre iOS 4.0 version" the answer has to be no.

Comment: You can use ARC in iOS 4 but instead of using `weak` you have to use `unsafe_unretained` and take care of setting to `nil` when neccessary.

Comment: Thanks rokjarc but OP was asking about making ARC work below iOS 4 version.. I will mention about `unsafe_unretained` in the answer too..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Thanks for Answering, but can you please give me more clarification on it.

Comment: Which part you need clarification?

Comment: @Krishnabhadra I have been asked this question in the interview and as per my knowledge i replied him because i tried this on my own by testing it on the device,**So the Interviewer asked me If ARC enabled  apps does not work below iOS 4.0, then whats the use of that app. I got bit confused on his reply, so please Explane it a bit.**, as i m new to this iOS technology, i am expecting the conformation from the experienced guys.

Comment: Regarding question _what is the use of the app?_  there are lot of apps currently available in market which only support iOS 5.0 or above(I am not even talking about iOS 4.0 and above). If you target your app iOS 4.0 and above then you are targeting around 95% of iphone users, which is good enough for any developer. Also ARC is only one of the concern when choosing OS Targets. There are many other concerns relating to hardware (example : glyroscope which available on iphone 4 only). In short around 90 percent of new apps uploaded to app store these days only support iOS 4.0 and above.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot enable ARC in *armv6*. If the architecture is *armv6 armv7* or only *armv7* then you can enable ARC.

So in response to your question: it will not work below iOS4 versions.

Answer (score 1):

Add armv6 and armv7 in your Architecture, this is supported for all versions